# ScriptResource.axd not found over the load balancer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ssrs-2012

The applcation works fine when I try to access it  by server1 and server2 indivisually.
But I try to access it using load balancer it gives me the below  error.

The resource cannot be found. 
 Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /ScriptResource.axd

I have added the below line under system.Webserver -> handlers section.

Still no help.

Can anybody suggest me where I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Joy

Comment: 'The load balancer', which product/version? - Have you looked at the logfiles of the load balancer and the webservers? Are both being reached?

Comment: Are you using the same hostname eg "http://mywebserver/ScriptResource.axd" or whatever when you try it on your 2 servers and when you use the load balancer?

Comment: When I run the application using LoadBalancer, in fiddler I have a get request for xyz.com/ScriptResource.axd, for which I am getting 404 error.But when I run the application using server I dont have any get request for ScriptResource.axd. Automatically I am getting 200 for Reserved.ReportviewerWebcontrol.axd which is next line in fiddler.In load Balancer case this statement is not executed because of the above error.

Comment: Anyone managed to resolved this? I dun have access to the lb but my infra team doesnt know where to look